# EF Core Linq query containing Any cannot be translated

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have the following query :

```
IQueryable<Person> query = dbSet;
query = query.Where(x => PersonDto.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id && y.Name == x.Name);
```

Where `Person` is a model class and `PersonDto` is a Dto class and both of them contain an Id property and a Name one.

For some reason this simple query returns an error that EF Core cannot translate it to SQL and I don't understand why.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the duplicate answer doesn't explain why it works - maybe you could add some clarification.

Comment: It works because EF can translate `Contains()`, but cannot translate `Any()`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand how `Contains()` works with a single property but here I have two.

Comment: You say `PersonDto` is a Dto class, but you're using it like it's a collection.  What's it's exact type?